# Add completed date to google sheet once I move it from the working sheet to the completed sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Good afternoon;

I am working on a google sheet with 2 columns "New Data" and "Completed". I have the New Data set with a check box that moves the row to the completed sheet once it is checked. Once on the completed sheet I would like to fill in a date and time stamp under comlumn E to show when it was moved to completed. What I have so far is listed below. Currently when it moves over from new data nothing happens. I also have a trigger set on addCompleteDate to work onEdit. Any help is appreciated.

```
function onEdit(e) {
 const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
 const r = e.range;
 if(src.getName() != "New Data" || r.columnStart != 6 || r.rowStart == 1) return;
 const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Completed");
 src.getRange(r.rowStart, 1, 1 ,4).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,4));
 src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
}

function addCompleteDate(e){
  const row = e.source.range.getRow();
  const col = e.source.getSheetByName("Completed").columns[2];

  if(col && col != "" && row > 1 ){
    const currentDate = new Date();
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 5).setValue(currentDate);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share both scripts.  We can probably combine the and avoid unwanted interactions

Comment: Good morning ; 

Thank you, I have added both functions that I currently have.

Answer (score 0):

#### Just combine them together

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "New Data" && e.range.columnStart == 6 || e.range.rowStart > 1) {
    const dsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Completed");
    const dnr = dsh.getLastRow() + 1;
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 4).moveTo(dsh.getRange(dnr, 1, 1, 4));
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
    dsh.getRange(dnr,5).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```